# How to get distinct rows based on the distinct(column) selected using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

It could be pretty simple but I searched and attempted for past day but my solution does not work.

My `data_table` looks like this:

```
SprintID, Start_Date,                  End_Date
--------------------------------------------------------------
S100      2019-01-01 08:00:16.793      2019-01-10 06:59:00.000
S101      2019-01-11 08:00:19.793      2019-01-20 06:59:00.000
S101      2019-01-11 09:00:16.793      2019-01-20 07:14:00.000
S101      2019-01-11 11:00:16.793      2019-01-20 08:32:00.000
S102      2019-01-21 08:00:16.793      2019-01-30 09:19:00.000
S102      2019-01-21 09:45:16.793      2019-01-30 06:59:00.000
...
```

Notice that in the above data we can see that the `Start_Date` and `End_Date` has the same `day` but different `time`

**What do I want?**

What I am looking for is a single/distinct value of `SprintID` with corresponding `Start_Date` and `End_Date`

```
SprintID, Start_Date,                  End_Date
--------------------------------------------------------------
S100      2019-01-01 08:00:16.793      2019-01-10 06:59:00.000
S101      2019-01-11 08:00:19.793      2019-01-20 06:59:00.000
S102      2019-01-21 08:00:16.793      2019-01-30 09:19:00.000
...
```

**What did I do?**

I used the following code but it does not do what I am excepting:

**Method 1**

```
SELECT DISTINCT(SprintID), Start_Date, End_Date
FROM data_table
```

**Method 2**

```
SELECT SprintID, Start_Date, End_Date
FROM data_table
GROUP BY SprintID, Start_Date, End_Date
ORDER BY SprintID, Start_Date, End_Date
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select d.*
from (select d.*,
             row_number() over (partition by sprintid order by start_date) as seqnum
      from data_table dt
    ) d
where seqnum = 1;
```

The above returns a row with the earliest `start_date`.  However, you can adjust the `order by` to control what row you want.  The expression `order by newid()` returns a random row.

Comment: Thank you for composing the answer. It works as expected. Would you know the reason why the `distinct(SprintID)` not selecting a single value of other columns ?

Comment: @floss . . . `distinct` is not a function.  `select distinct` is a clause where the `distinct` applies to all columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` as follows:

```
SELECT SprintID, Start_Date, End_Date
  FROM data_table t
 Where not exists 
       (Select 1 from data_table tt
         Where t.SprintID = tt.sprint_id And tt.start_date < t.start_date)
```